# Maximal consistency proof for set of propositional logic with specific restriction?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

I ran into struggle when I comes to one sentence on logic.

> Why the set of all propositional that under any valuation has value
>   `1` is not maximal consistent ?

I read it on my books, without adding detail as a result.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\Gamma$ be the set of all logical tautologies(i.e. formulas which are evaluated to 1 under every interpretation), and A a propositional variable. The formula A is no logical tautology, so $A \notin \Gamma$ but $\Gamma \cup \{A\}$ is consistent.

Comment: you means maximally consistent ?

Comment: @MousaHvoize No. $\Gamma \cup \{A\}$ is a consistent, proper extension of $\Gamma$, therefore $\Gamma$ is not maximal consistent.

Comment: is there any proof?

Comment: @MousaHvoize This proves that $\Gamma$ is not maximal consistent

Comment: so set of all atomic propositions or set of all propositions is maximally consistent ?

Comment: @MousaHvoize the first is consistent but not maximal consistent, the second is not even consistent

Answer (score 0):

If I interpret your question correctly, isn't this just that your set of sentences, $\Gamma$, contains non-controversial sentences (valuated always true).  Now take a sentence, say $A \ne B$, or $\exists x \exists y (x \ne y)$, depending if we're talking about propositional or first-order logic.  Then there's a way to make valuation or interpretation true or false, proving that the sentence is not in $\Gamma$ but also allowing it to be extended consistently.

Comment: there is a typo.

Comment: @James are you agree ?